# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed:

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-studio

Error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.appmaster.akash.messageplus, PID: 14373
                                                                             android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: UserData.RecieversID (code 1555)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:734)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1579)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1525)
                                                                                 at com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Chat.mMessagesSent(Chat.java:918)
                                                                                 at com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Chat.sendMessage(Chat.java:709)
                                                                                 at com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Chat.access$900(Chat.java:76)
                                                                                 at com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Chat$5.onClick(Chat.java:442)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

**Inserting**

```
 MainData helper = new MainData(this); //Change the name to your Helper Class name
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_ID, MessageRecieverId);
    contentValues.put(KEY_NAME, MessageRecieverName);
    contentValues.put(KEY_MESSAGES_SENT, 0);
    contentValues.put(KEY_MESSAGES_RECIEVED, 0);
    contentValues.put(KEY_TIME_SPENT, "");

    long returnVariable = db.insert(TABLE_USER_DATA,null,contentValues);
    if (returnVariable == -1) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Nope", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

No problem in inserting but while updating im getting this error

**Updating**

```
 MainData helper = new MainData(this); //Change the name to your Helper Class name
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();int userData = 0;
    Cursor data2 = helper.getUserData();
    while (data2.moveToNext()) {
        userData = data2.getInt(data2.getColumnIndex("MessagesSent"));
    }
    ContentValues contentValues2 = new ContentValues();
    contentValues2.put(KEY_ID, MessageRecieverId);
    contentValues2.put(KEY_MESSAGES_SENT, userData+1);
    long returnVariable2 = db.update(TABLE_USER_DATA, contentValues2,null,null);
    if (returnVariable2 == -1) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Nope", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //-1 means there was an error updating the values
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"uf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Anyone know why this is so?  .................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Because you are violating the database's constraint. The column ``UserData.RecieversID`` may only hold unique values which you seem to ignore in your code while updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely inserting using a value for the **id** column (**KEY_ID**). Odds on this column is defined as either **INTEGER PRIMARY KEY** or **INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT**.

Typically you do not specify a value for such a column as SQLite will assign a unique value (typically 1 greater than the highest assigned).

If you specify a value for such a column and a row in the table already has that value in the column then the **UNIQUE** constraint implied by **PRIMARY KEY** will be violated as it's against the rule that a **PRIMARY KEY** has to be **unique**.

I'd suggest that you want to use :-

```
MainData helper = new MainData(this); //Change the name to your Helper Class name
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
//contentValues.put(KEY_ID, MessageRecieverId); //<<<<<<<<<< COMMENTED OUT (can delete the line)
contentValues.put(KEY_NAME, MessageRecieverName);
contentValues.put(KEY_MESSAGES_SENT, 0);
contentValues.put(KEY_MESSAGES_RECIEVED, 0);
contentValues.put(KEY_TIME_SPENT, "");

long returnVariable = db.insert(TABLE_USER_DATA,null,contentValues);
if (returnVariable == -1) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Nope", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**returnVariable** will then be the value of the **id** column (**KEY_ID**) that was assigned when the row was inserted.

- Note **id** column does not necessarily mean that the column is named **id** but that it's a special column due to how it is defined. That is, by specifying INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, the column is actually an alias of the normally hidden **rowid** column (unless the TABLE is defined with the WITHOUT ROWID phrase).

You may find reading  [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) helpful.

Comment: But i want to update data to a row where KEY_ID = MessageRecieverId

Comment: So if i insert it using a random id then i wont be able to fetch the row as there is no foreign key so i have to identify only using primary key which is ID

Comment: You are not inserting a random key. You are letting SQLite generate the key (**id**) (actually SQLite does this anyway, rather you are making that value more readily available by defining an alias) which will be unique and hence how you can **id**entify any row. The value returned from the insert is that value. When you retrieve a row or rows (e.g. from a listview) then you include the id in the Cursor and thus have access to the id say when an item is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you made the same newbie mistake I did. When using **db.update** to modify row values, you DO NOT specify which row by added KEY_ID to `ContentValues`. Instead you must use a where clause for this purpose. A where clause is one of the parameters passed to db.update.

Explanation: `ContentValues` contains column-name/value pairs to apply to selected row(s). The where clause indicates which row(s) to select. It is possible (and common) to select multiple rows. Passing null for *where* clause updates every row in the database - so be carefull